# Confused about the usage of "have been" in the sentence

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context

> A 50-year-old former air-force captain, entrepreneur and chemistry teacher with Teach for America, Mrs Houlahan appears, **crucially, to have been none of those impressive things for political effect.**

The sentence is an excerpt from an [article](https://www.economist.com/news/united-states/21737050-many-cultural-clashes-president-has-engineered-work-his-advantage-not). I am confused about the meaning of the bold part which seems to lack a verb.

Comment: *Crucially* is a parenthetical modifying the entire clause headed by *appears*; the remainder of your bolded passage is an **infinitival** complement (***to** have been*) to *appears*, as in *She appears to have been sincere*. The infinitival is cast in the perfect construction to mark it as a past eventuality.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, it means that Mrs Houlahan didn't do any of the aforementioned things to improve her political standing or to achieve a political effect.

The reason why it seems to lack a verb is that the sentence starts before the comma:

> Mrs Houlahan appears, crucially, to have been none of those impressive things for political effect.

And therefore, simplified, it is

> Mrs Houlahan appears to have been none of those impressive things for political effect.

I hope that helps.